# Passing a tag in array using phalcon framework

Tags: php, html, phalcon

I am using phalcon framework and I want to pass a tag with JavaScript function as href. This is my code:

```
$arr[] = array($first, $second,"<a href='javascript:openOutwardFrm('inventory/outward/?categoryid=2&amp;itemid=1')'><i class='fa fa-edit'></i></a>");
```

The problem is in the href section. It's only taking "*javascript:openOutwardFrm(*".
I want the href string as *javascript:openOutwardFrm('inventory/outward/?categoryid=2&itemid=1')*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pay attention to your quotes: as far as the browser is concerned, the link's href is just `'javascript:openOutwardFrm('` (as that's the bit between the quotes), and the rest of the stuff that follows is garbage.

If we use double quotes for the href and class then things become slightly clearer to work with.

Let's start with this string: `<a href="javascript:openOutwardFrm('inventory/outward/?categoryid=2&amp;itemid=1')"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>` (notice how, for now, the quotes are nice and balanced - the href is in double quotes, and the function argument is in single quotes).

Now, we want to use this in PHP, to add to our array. We'll use double quotes to enclose it, which means we need to escape every double quote that's already present, by putting a backslash in front of it: `$html = "<a href=\"javascript:openOutwardFrm('inventory/outward/?categoryid=2&amp;itemid=1')\"><i class=\"fa fa-edit\"></i></a>"` (notice how the quotes are still balanced).

Putting this back in your original example: `$arr[] = array($first, $second, "<a href=\"javascript:openOutwardFrm('inventory/outward/?categoryid=2&amp;itemid=1')\"><i class=\"fa fa-edit\"></i></a>");`.

Make sense?

Comment: yup its working thnk you... i have one more question in this example how can i pass categoryid & itemid as php variable

Comment: There isn't enough information in your comment to begin answering it. Please open a new question and provide all details.

Comment: right now the parameters is static in the JavaScript call (categoryid=2 & itemid=1) here i want to pass php variable like (categoryid=$a & itemid=$b

Comment: Again, if this answer fixes your original problem, please click the tick next to it to accept it. You can literally write what you just wrote in that comment: `"<a href.....categoryid=$a&itemid=$b......"`